# JAX-RS Post requests works fine locally but doesn't on Heroku. What can it be?

Tags: java, heroku, unity-game-engine, jersey

I uploaded the server project by WAR file in Heroku, Jersey is okay working locally, just isn't in the server, so annotations seems okay. JSP pages age working both locally and remotely with Spring MVC and Hibernate in a Maven project. URLs seems okay to the request. It returns me 500 Internal Server Error, even when I try by post http request online. What can it be?

*Unity Client:*

```
 public class Test{

//Simplified version of the code:

public string Testing() {

    string url =  URL.HEROKUPOST.url;           

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField( "JsonRequest", "JsonRequest");
    form.AddField( "Action", "Action");  
    WWW www = new WWW( url, form );

    yield return www;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
    yield return  www.data;
    }
    else 
    {
    yield return www.error ;
    }
}
```

*Java Server:*

```
 @Path("/helloworld")
 public class JSONController
 {
  @POST @Produces("application/json")   
    public String unityRequest(@FormParam("JsonRequest") String requisition, @FormParam("Action")String action) 
    {         
      return "Okay";    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you see an error message in the logs when you run `heroku logs -t` for your app?

Comment: I got it sending post request online in requestmanager.com (http://txt.do/dd4wn)

I don't manage heroku cmd very well.

Comment: You need to get the error from the logs. If you ran `heroku deploy:war` you can run `heroku logs`. Or you can go to https://dashboard.heroku.com and view the logs from there.

Comment: @codefinger I can't find logs in Heroku, I tried app logs in more options in dashboard but seems to just appear the last line from each day log or something like that, I think I had sucess doing it in CMD and I got this info: http://textuploader.com/ddml7